Spring Boot - Open API - Swagger extremely slow to load / doesn't load
I really don't understand why Swagger UI is extremely slow to load.
My settings are:
spring doc settings
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    enabled: true
    version: openapi_3_1
    path: /v3/api-docs
  swagger-ui:
    enabled: true
    path: /swagger-ui.html
    url: /v3/api-docs
    operations-sorter: method
    config-url: ${RESOURCE_SERVER_PREFIX}/swagger-config
  show-actuator: false
  enable-kotlin: true
  enable-spring-security: true
  enable-default-api-docs: true
  default-produces-media-type: application/json

/v3/api-docs loads in <5 seconds.
But as soon as I try to access /swagger-ui.html, I get this

And I have to wait, and wait, and wait.
Then I get this

And my rest api stalls, here

And I can't even call another normal endpoint after this. The server remains in a forever wait..
Any ideas on how to trouble shoot this?

If you have logger configured in the application, enable the trace log for the particular component(org.springdoc) and check if there are any red flags.

It was the time-out limiter in my BFF. For some reason, it didn't like the .js, and .css files being served when accessing /swagger-ui.html  - I included a filter to bypass the time limiter, when that end point is accessed. I think it was also to do with when accessing swagger-ui.html - a lot of the end points are being accesed in quick succession, which the time out limiter did not like
